# How to Splunk for the last log matching a string for each Id

Tags: logging, splunk

Let's say you want to find splunk results that match the string "Sending status to server" (doing the query index=* "Sending status to server" ) . And you get the following results.

1. Sending Status to Server ... jobId=1
2. Sending Status to Server ... jobId=1
3. Sending Status to Server ... jobId=0
4. Sending Status to Server ... jobId=0

How do I alter this query so that I get the last result matching this string for each jobId? The results of that query in this set of data would be

1. Sending Status to Server ... jobId=1
2. Sending Status to Server ... jobId=0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me tell you that doing index=* is NOT a good idea unless you really want to search in ALL indices. I would suggest to use specific index name.

Now, to answer your question -
You can use [dedup](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/SearchReference/Dedup) command for that. Also use `sortby` argument to sort on time in descending order.

Your SPL would look like: `index=myindex | dedup 1 jobid sortby -time`

(or if you REALLY want to search all indices: `index=* | dedup 1 jobid sortby -time`)

My sample data was:

```
"time","message","jobid"
"2016-10-26 13:00:00","Sending Status to Server","jobId=1"
"2016-10-26 12:00:00","Sending Status to Server","jobId=1"
"2016-10-26 11:00:00","Sending Status to Server","jobId=0"
"2016-10-26 10:00:00","Sending Status to Server","jobId=0"
```

And my search result was [image: as shown in this image]